# Laravel Generate User data

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new in Laravel and I want to generate fake data for the table Users.
Right know this is working fine:

**UserFactory.php**

```
$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'password' => '$2y$10$TKh8H1.PfQx37YgCzwiKb.KjNyWgaHb9cbcoQgdIVFlYg7B77UdFm', // secret
        'remember_token' => str_random(10),
    ];
});
```

**UsersTableSeeder.php**

```
public function run() {
        factory(App\User::class, 5)->create();
}
```

**DatabaseSeeder.php**

```
public function run() {
        $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
}
```

The previous code generates 5 rows in the User table and it is OK.

Now I would like to generate one more extra user (
in addition of the 5 rows already generated) with fixed fields like:

```
return [
        'name' => 'user test',
        'email' => 'user@mycompany.com',
        'password' => '$2y$10$TKh8H1.PfQx37YgCzwiKb.KjNyWgaHb9cbcoQgdIVFlYg7B77UdFm', // secret
        'remember_token' => str_random(10),
    ];
```

Where I have to put the above code? Do I have to generate a new UserFactory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put the following code in your `UsersTableSeeder.php`s `run()` method right after your existing code:

```
factory(App\User::class)->create([
        'name' => 'user test',
        'email' => 'user@mycompany.com',
        'password' => '$2y$10$TKh8H1.PfQx37YgCzwiKb.KjNyWgaHb9cbcoQgdIVFlYg7B77UdFm', // secret
        'remember_token' => str_random(10),
    ]);
```

You could also use `'password' => bcrypt(USERPASSWORDHERE),` to create an encrypted string of USERPASSWORDHERE